# set tw=80 isn't working properly

Tags: vim

So, I try to use a command in vim to set a total column for each line in my .c file. however when I enter command `:set tw=132 gggqG` it turn a code from this:

```
int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  while(i<10)
  {
    cout<<"1";
  }
}
```

to :

```
int main(){ int i = 0; while(i<10){cout<<"1";}}
```

am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`gq` means "format text" -- it is meant to be used on text paragraphs, not source code.

If you want to format C code, try *[Is it possible to format C++ code with VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506776/is-it-possible-to-format-c-code-with-vim)*.

Answer (score 1):

The `gq` command is meant for *text*; in a C file, you can use it to re-format multi-line comments (with correct `'formatoptions'` and `'comments'` options), but you cannot use it for the source code itself.

There, Vim offers re-indenting via `=`, i.e. `gg=G` to re-indent the whole buffer. If you need something more fancy, you have to delegate this to an external tool, e.g. `:%!astyle`.