# Indent code using vim autocommand

Tags: vim, autocmd

I want use the indent linux utility to indent the current file on saving. I tried

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.[ch] :!indent -kr -nut %
```

in my .vimrc file (~/.vim).

Manually I tried that command

```
:!indent -kr -nut %
```

it works only after prompting me to load the file, as below,

```
See ":help W12" for more info.
[O]K, (L)oad File:
```

Comment: autocmd BufWritePost *.[ch] :!indent -kr -nut % works but still asks for load file similar to manual command

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `BufWritePre` because that modifies your file before saving it. Instead, try doing `BufWritePost`:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.[ch] !indent -kr -nut %
```

This will still ask you to hit enter, but it doesn't prompt to load the file when I test it. If you don't want to have to hit enter after saving, you can change this to:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.[ch] exec "!indent -kr -nut %" | redraw
```

Also, note how I removed the `:` from your command. This is because `autocmd` looks for an ex command, so the `:` is unneeded.

Comment: It is still prompts for Load or Ok

Comment: @vishwanathpatil Well, I"m not sure what to tell you because it doesn't prompt me when I run it locally. Sorry

Comment: autocmd VimLeave *.[ch] exec "!indent -kr -nut %" | redraw  , using VimLeave it works fine

Comment: From a [similar answer using `astyle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2506955/248390), I used this to format Golang code; in `~/.vim/plugin/go.vim` I added `autocmd BufWritePre *.go silent! exec "%!goimports"`; unfortunately it still move the cursor to the top of the file