# Is it a good idea to align equal in c?

Tags: c, coding-style

What I wrote previously:

```
int abc = 0;
char *str = NULL;
struct B *b = NULL;
```

My boss asked me to align equal like this:

```
int abc     = 0;
char *str   = NULL;
struct B *b = NULL;
```

Well, I can live with this above one, but how about this??

```
int abc                                 = 0;
char *str                               = NULL;
struct B *b                             = NULL;
struct VeryLongStruct *very_long_struct = NULL;
```

What is the suggested way?

Comment: No. Use auto formatting.  Manual formatting is not efficient programing.

Comment: It's beautiful, for about 6 seconds after you do it, then it becomes unaligned and you either make it your life's work to keep fixing it or move on to important things.

Comment: @chux how to do auto formatting in vim?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506776/is-it-possible-to-format-c-code-with-vim

Comment: @Sato, there are many available tools.  A good approach is for your group to agree on one and use it.

Comment: Isn't this POB?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Exactly. Personally I rarely do this,, other people in my group do.. whatever. My projects are generally new, proof-of-concept demonstrations on a tight schedule (just like everyone else). Pretty formatting is the least of my concerns. Although, if I'm modifying a file that has an established format, I try to throw my personal preferences out the window and adhere to what's already been established. But I'd tell your boss to can it ;)

Answer (score 1):

As with most subjective questions, there are good and bad points. Selecting one from each side at random:

1. It's a *good* thing because it makes the code easier to read.
2. It's a *bad* thing because keeping them aligned (when you add a longer variable name for example) will result in unnecessary changes. Specifically, it's annoying when git history shows a slew of lines that have changed when they actually *haven't.*